# R function to find which of 3 variables correlates most with another value?

Tags: r, anova, linguistics, t-test

I am conducting a study that analyzes speakers' production and measures their average F2 values. What I need is an R function that allows me to find a relationship for these F2 values with 3 other variables, and if there is, which one is the most significant. These variables have been coded as 1, 2, or 3 for things like "yes" "no" answers or whether responses are positive, neutral or negative (1, 2, 3 respectively).

Is there a particular technique or R function/test that we can use to approach this problem? I've considered using ANOVA or a T-Test but am unsure if this will give me what I need.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding the questions, you can use the `cor()` function and loop through with each of the variables to find the pair with the highest correlation. Can you provide sample data?

Comment: Helpful? https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/893/how-to-get-correlation-between-two-categorical-variable-and-a-categorical-variab

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution might look like this. Here, the `cor` function is used. Read its help page (`?cor`) to understand what is calculated. By default, the Pearson correlation coefficient is used. The function below return the variable with the highest Pearson correlation with respect to the reference variable.

```
set.seed(111)

x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100)
z <- rnorm(100)

ref <- 0.5*x + 0.5*rnorm(100)

find_max_corr <- function(vars, ref){
  val <- sapply(vars, cor, y = ref)
  val[which.max(val)]
}

find_max_corr(list('x' = x, 'y' = y, 'z' = z), ref)
```